# Imageview position not behaving as expected

Tags: android

I' using full screen and locking to portrait. In the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

In the layout I have an imageview and two buttons:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

At the start I load my own image into the imageview:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //from .xml 
Drawable newPhoneImage;
newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);
imageView.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);
```

On both my emulators this shows the image at the top of screen as expected.

I then draw up a bitmap and replace the Image:

```
sBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(557, 580,Config.ARGB_8888);
//draw the bimap image
BitmapDrawable nimage;
nimage = new BitmapDrawable(sBitmap);
imageView.setImageDrawable(nimage);
```

On the large emulator(WVGA800 400x800) the image is at the top as expected.

On the small emulator(QVGA 240x320) and on my phone(240x320) the image is 35 pixels down from the top.

Why are they different?

I can scroll the image up:

```
imageView.scrollTo(0, 35); //this will put image at top
```

How can I find this value? Nothing like this will work:

```
int offset = imageView.getTop();// it just = height of image
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your image is too big for the screen.

Setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the XML may help.

Also, you may try getting the screen width and using it:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width/557*580,Config.ARGB_8888);
```

To create an image of the correct size. Try settings both of these things at the same time.

On another note, you can just:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //from .xml 
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_on);
```

To simplify the code a little bit.